# SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): (Closed)

Tags: android, sqlite

The App forces closed everytime I run it. When I checked the logcat, this was the error that keeps on popping out.

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM tblresultsWHEREtopid=1ANDusname=fbbh
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my snippet from DBHELPER: TOP_ID is initialized as a string.

```
public List<Result> getAllResult() {


    String qry3 = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_RESULT + "WHERE" + TOP_ID + "=" + "1" + "AND" + USER_NAME + "=" + user;

    Log.e(LOG, qry3);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(qry3, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Result result = new Result();
            result.setResultID(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(RESULT_ID)));
            result.setUserName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(USER_NAME)));
            result.setAverage(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(AVERAGE)));
            result.setTopicID(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TOP_ID)));

            results.add(result);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: change `"AND"` with `" AND "`

Comment: That's a most comman mistake when you are an absolute beginner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is problem in your concat code

```
String qry3 = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_RESULT + "WHERE" + TOP_ID + "=" + "1" + "AND" + USER_NAME + "=" + user;
```

I think you should add space between `TABLE_RESULT` and `WHERE` and a space after the "WHERE" and same goes for cocat for `AND`. 
Also, if your `USER_NAME` is a string, you would need to put it inside `'`
Something like

```
String qry3 = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_RESULT + " WHERE " + TOP_ID + "=" + "1" + " AND " + USER_NAME + "='" + user +"'";
```

Comment: I changed it, but here's in the log cat:
no such column: user1 (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM tblresults WHERE topid =  1  AND usname = user1

Comment: @user2204221 may be you don't have usname column in your database. Check your table clearly.

Comment: when i used to get all column in the table, the data was there, but when I tried to ask for the specific column, it keeps on getting an error

Comment: @user2204221 what happens when you make the query without the user_name condition? Also, can you tell name of all columns in your `TABLE_RESULT`?

Comment: @user2204221 Ok I think I see your problem, your `user` is a string, you should concat it inside `'`. I have also updated the answer. Give it a try.

Comment: @ShamasS The columns are RESULT_ID, USER-NAME, AVERAGE, TOP-ID

Answer (score 4):

Put gap for text within quotes:

```
String qry3 = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_RESULT + " WHERE " + TOP_ID + " = " + "1" + " AND " + USER_NAME + " = " + user;
```

Comment: I changed it, but here's in the log cat: no such column: user1 (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM tblresults WHERE topid = 1 AND usname = user1